# Need help passing utm and gclid parameters past a 301 redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, query-string

Whenever I test query parameters domain.com/gclid=test it returns only domain.com and strips the parameters.  It does the same with utm parameters.  We need the parameters to be appended for tracking purposes.  We did recently migrate web sites and are using a 301 redirect.  I'm not 100% sure that it is the issue but it could be.  It is a wordpress site and our .htaccess file is the wordpress standard like so:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I just need to configure the site to pass all parameters through.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the `QSA` flag: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: @cOle2 - Thanks for your response, I tried adding QSA tag after [L] in both rewrite rules so that it looks like RewriteRule 6index\.php$ - [L,QSA] but the parameters are still not passing.

Comment: Can you show your 301 rules?

Comment: @anubhava it looks like all redirects have been setup using the cPanel interface.  Each redirect has permanent for type and match www. is checked. I don't know if this helps at all.

Comment: cPanel is just a medium, eventually these rules either exist in Apache config or in .htaccess. Until I see those rules it is difficult to guess what's wrong.